# "avrebbe potuto essere diverso"

Tags: grammar, verbs, auxiliary-verb

Certe volte mi chiedo, è corretto dire

> ... sarebbe potuto essere diverso ...

o, si dovrebbe dire

> ... avrebbe potuto essere diverso ...

C'è una regola che governa questo costrutto? E se c'è, si applica anche a

> ... sarebbe dovuto essere diverso ...

e, correlativamente, a

> ... avrebbe dovuto essere diverso ...

?

Comment: +1 perché è un punto dolente anche per molti madrelingua

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In realtà, è una questione abbastanza intricata. Generalmente, si sceglie l'ausiliare del verbo retto dal servile, per esempio: *avrebbe potuto mangiare* (come "avrebbe mangiato"); *è dovuto andare* (come "è andato").
Però se il verbo servile è seguito dal verbo *essere*, si usa l'ausiliare ***avere***, per esempio: *avrei voluto essere presente, avrebbe dovuto essere diverso*.

La situazione cambierebbe, se vi fosse anche la presenza di un pronome personale o riflessivo atono (*mi, ti, gli/le, ci, vi, si*) o di particelle atone come *ci/vi* (locative, presentative, fraseologiche):
- si usa l'ausiliare *essere* in caso di anticipazione del pronome (*gli sarebbe potuto essere utile; ci saremmo dovuti essere tutti*),
- *avere* in caso di posticipazione del pronome (*avrebbe potuto essergli utile; avremmo dovuto esserci tutti*).

- [Accademia della Crusca 1](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/ausiliare-verbi-servili)
- [Accademia della Crusca 2](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/scelta-ausiliari)
- [Enciclopedia dell'Italiano (2010)](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-ausiliari_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/)
- [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_367.html)