# "Che sarebbe potuto essere mortale" oppure "che avrebbe potuto essere mortale"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, phrase-choice, conditional-mood

In un esercizio di italiano (modello di esame per ottenere il certificato di livello B2 della "Generalirat de Catalunya") ho trovato questa frase:

> Gianluca, proprio in questa curva, l'anno scorso evitò uno scontro frontale **che sarebbe potuto essere mortale**.

Tuttavia, per quanto si spiega in [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/1468/707), a me sembra che questa frase si dovrebbe scrivere in questo modo:

> Gianluca, proprio in questa curva, l'anno scorso evitò uno scontro frontale **che avrebbe potuto essere mortale**.

È così oppure la presenza del pronome "che" fa cambiare la situazione rispetto a quella esposta in [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1466/707)?

Comment: A mio parere il "che" non modifica la questione. Credo proprio che nell'esercizio ci sia un errore nell'uso dell'ausiliare, errore però comprensibile, vista la regola, un po' complicata.

Comment: Sembra che questa domanda sia diventata tanto "famosa" che persino sia stata convertita in un [esercizio su Facebook](https://m.facebook.com/impariamoitaliano/posts/10160662307373125).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ho appena installato l'[app "La Grammatica italiana" di Treccani.it](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.mit.lagrammaticaitaliana) sul mio cellulare. Là ho trovato questa spiegazione:

> HO DOVUTO ESSERE O SONO DOVUTO ESSERE?
>
> Anche sui giornali può capitare di leggere l’ausiliare *essere* con il verbo servile e l’infinito passivo
>
> mancava il siero antiofidico in grado di salvargli la vita, che è dovuto essere recuperato, con una veloce staffetta della Polizia Stradale, a Foggia («La Repubblica»)
>
> La regola, che vale sia per l’infinito *essere* sia per l’infinito passivo, prevede l’ausiliare *avere*
>
> **Ho dovuto** / **potuto** / **voluto** essere severo
>
> **Ho dovuto** / **potuto** / **voluto** essere criticato.

L'esempio di errore nell'uso dell’ausiliare tratto dal giornale "La Repubblica" è appunto una frase col pronome "che". Quindi, come ha detto @Benedetta nel suo commento, la presenza del "che" nella frase non modifica la regola valida nella situazione della domanda. Cioè, la frase corretta in quel caso è

> Gianluca, proprio in questa curva, l'anno scorso evitò uno scontro frontale **che avrebbe potuto essere mortale**.

Answer (score 1):

Di solito nel parlato comune capita di ascoltare entrambe le forme, ma qualora tu volessi essere preciso e formale:

- Quando hai il verbo modale "**potere**"+verbo all'**infinito** (diverso da essere)

http://www.corriere.it/Rubriche/Scioglilingua/2003/18aprile.shtml
"La regola grammaticale dice che l'ausiliare da usare con i verbi servili è quello proprio del verbo all'infinito." 
Per fare un esempio: si dice "Non ho potuto rispondere al telefono". Infatti l'ausiliare del verbo rispondere è "avere", è corretto dire "**Ho risposto** al telefono", non "Sono risposto al telefono", dunque bisogna usare il verbo **avere**

- Quando hai il verbo modale "**potere**"+**essere**+**aggettivo**:

http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_367.html
"La scelta del verbo ausiliare per i tempi composti del verbo servile seguito dall'infinito essere è semplice: si deve usare **avere**. Dunque, "avrebbero potuto essere."
Per fare un esempio: si dice "Avrebbe potuto essergli utile", invece che "Sarebbe potuto essergli utile". Ma, nella vita quotidiana, la seconda forma è molto più ricorrente della prima.